# Merging three 1D into one multidimensional array with for loop

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to understand arrays and loops. So I would like to merge three 1D arrays into one. Can you give me so advices how to do that? Do you know any good trainings for good understanding this subject in programming?
Here we got code, thats what i figure out for a now:

```
public class Company {
public static void main(String[] args) {


    int[] arr1 = new int[]{1, 2, 3};
    int[] arr2 = new int[]{4, 5, 6};
    int[] arr3 = new int[]{7, 8, 9};

    int[][] arrX = new int[3][3];


    for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            arrX[i][j] = arr1[i] + arr2[j]; //Dont how to resolve this       without using any "Java built-in methods"
        }

    }

    for(int x = 0; x < arrX.length; x++){
        for (int y = 0; y <arrX[x].length; y++){
           System.out.print(arrX[x][y] + " ");
        }
    }

  //  System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(tabx));

}
```

}

Comment: You mean, you want a matrix, where every row is equal to an array?

Comment: simplest way will be `int[][] arr4 = { arr1, arr2, arr3 };`

Comment: Yes it is the simplest, but i want to make it with for loop.
@ctst yes.

Comment: are you doing matrix addition, or matrix combining?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close to a solution, but you only need one loop (the outer one):

```
for (int i = 0; i<3; i++) {
    arrX[1][i] = arr1[i];
    arrX[2][i] = arr2[i];
    arrX[3][i] = arr3[i];
}
```

Iterating over the three arrays will only work *after* you merged them together in one data structure.

Of course the easier way is to use this:

```
arrX[1] = arr1;
arrX[2] = arr2;
arrX[3] = arr3;
```

Or shorter:

```
int[][] arrX = new int[][] {arr1, arr2, arr3};
```

Or start creating it in the beginning:

```
int[][] arrX = new int[][] {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
```

Allow me to mention, that `Arrays` are a very basic data type - that in my humble opinion **should be avoided**. `Arrays` might be useful in extrem situations (embedded programming, high performance tasks, etc.) - but in general using `Collection`s is the way to go.

- Collections are easier to use
- Collections are "real" classes
- Collections do not have as bad performance as one might think

Try to use `List`s, `Set`s and `Map`s - or store structured data in meaningful fields of your own classes.

Comment: I don't know if this really matters, but it might be better if you said to use the inner for loop: "You are close to a solution, but you only need one loop (the outer one):". Some beginners might get confused because the outer is usually the rows. For us it doesn't really matter. Great explanation however!

Comment: Thank you for explanation. My bad side is getting in details to much. Now i know every thing i want. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add all three arrays into one data structure, you can use:

An ArrayList of arrays, 
   Or you can create a matrix like you initialized for arrx.

You cannot put three different integers in one array position for an int[] array. You can sum up all three values and store them in one position.

Matrix Version: In your for loop, you should do

```
int row = 0;
for (int column = 0; column < 3; column++){
    arrx[row][column] = arr1[column];  //Row zero stores arr1
    arrx[row+1][column] = arr2[column]; //Row one stores arr2
    arrx[row+2][column] = arr3[column]; //Row two stores arr3
}
```

I like to use the words row and column for integers to make it easier to see visually.

This is a basic hard-coded way for the rows. You can try to figure out how to keep track of the rows dynamically.

Comment: One point for using the correct indices of the matrix! Just change your `j` to column and it will work.